# Relationship between push reflection and permissions in a Git repository

Tags: git

I've cloned a repository and accidentally pushed a personal commit to that repository.
When I check my local SourceTree, it says the commit is reflected in the remote, but when I check the repository on GitHub, nothing seems to be affected. (I also re-downloaded the remote repository and the commits didn't seem to reflect anything.)

How is this being handled in this case?
(After all, if my commits are not reflected in the remote that others are also seeing, that's fine...)

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Have you checked the branches? If yes, it would be a good idea to check the git push output to see if even succeeded.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "push reflection", nor by "reflect anything" at the end of your parenthetical remark in your first paragraph.